# How do I implement bcrypt on OS X?

Tags: macos, encryption, bcrypt

I like to use [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) in my C or Xojo based program.

The openssl lib seems to provide blowfish based functions but I cannot figure out how to implement the bcrypt function, which takes a cost, salt and password parameter and returns the derived key.

In fact, the WP article states:

> The bcrypt function is the default password hash algorithm for BSD

As OSX is BSD based, I'd expect that the function would be exposed directly. But I can't find it.

Is there such a function available, or, if not, how to I implement one using the available lib functions (openssl, probably)?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is not an exposed API for bcrypt.  I always just use the [source](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) and then statically link the library against my C.